# Simple CSS issue - Blank space above

Tags: html, css

I am working on a coming soon page here: http://desertcinema.com/jheck/

However I run into some issue with regards an extra space at the top of my `<div class="background-filter"></div>` element.

[image]

Basically I have this CSS for this part:

```
.background-filter {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index:0;
    margin: 0;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
        -ms-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
}
```

I am wondering what is the reason why I have space at the top. This div must cover up the whole thing of the space with no spaces.

Any idea what's causing this and how to fix it? You can use CHROME INSPECT ELEMENT for the play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add style `top: 0;` to .background-filter.

The position of an element does not default to 0,0. It's position is set by default relative to the containing element.

Comment: While this works, the reason the position of the element was not 0,0 is because there is a character being displayed before the div.

Comment: Yes,  advise that you remove the  ">" character in the top of page. @MikkPoles

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra > character in your markup. Between your CSS files here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700,300|Roboto+Slab:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Fixing that gets rid of the space.

Answer (score 0):

```
body { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I'm not sure but it could be the body margin or padding?